# Android App Development- Adding an App inside the Overflow Menu

Tags: android, plugins, menu, overflow, action

I am interested to develop an app which when installed on a phone, add itself as an option to the action overflow menu and can be accessed within different apps. This is similar to plugin apps, like Google Street View and HP Print Service Plugin, which can be accessed withing Google Maps and different apps on the phone, respectively. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These sorts of actions are often part of a share menu where any app which declares certain standardized intent-filters can be launched from any app which can send a matching intent.

My recommendation is to read up on [Implicit Intents](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html#Receiving) here.